# ddply super slow, how can I speed up my calculation? R code modification requested:

Tags: r, performance, plyr

I have a data (delisle) and the following code which is taking days to run for my big data matrix. What is a substitute for ddply? Anyone please guide or help?

```
TYPE  SAMPLE probeA probeB probeC 
CatA  52 1.2 3.2 3.4
CatA  52 2.2 4.2 3.4
CatA  58 1.5 6.5 7.8
CatA  58 8.3 6.5 9.5
CatA  94 1.5 4.3 6.4
CatB  52 2.2 2.2 3.4
CatB  58 2.5 4.5 6.8
CatB  58 6.2 6.0 5.3
CatB  94 2.5 5.3 6.4
```

I computed for each "SAMPLE", for each probe, the fold change between catA and catB using ddply.

Output should be:

SAMPLE probe FC

```
52  probeA  mean(CatA)/mean(CatB)
52  probeB  mean(CatA)/mean(CatB)
58  probeA  mean(CatA)/mean(CatB)
58  probeB  mean(CatA)/mean(CatB)
```

My code is *EXTREMELY* SLOW for big data (20K rows and 5K columns):

```
 probenames <- as.vector(colnames(delisle))

 for (i in 3:ncol(delisle))
 {
 probe = probenames[i]

 Stats <- function(gs) {

 typeA.sub <- gs[which(gs$TYPE=="CatA"),]
 typeB.sub <- gs[which(gs$TYPE=="CatB"),]
 fc.AB = mean(typeA.sub[,i])/mean(typeB.sub[,i])
 fc.AC = 
 fc.BC = 
 data.frame(probe,fc.AB, fc.AC, fc.BC)
 }
 output <- ddply(.data=delisle, .variables="SAMPLE", .progress=progress_text(style=3), Stats)
 write.table(output,"SAMPLETYPE.txt",quote=F,sep="\t",append=T,col.names=F)
 }
```

Comment: I cannot run your code. It seems like key pieces are missing. For example, what is `probnames`? You may want to create a minimal reproducible example so we can better understand your desired output.

Comment: probenames <- as.vector(colnames(delisle))

Comment: help anybody with modifications?

Comment: Can you run `dput(df)` to make it easy to reproduce your data.frame?

Answer (score 0):

Is this giving you the expected result in a fast way?

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  select(-probeC) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -TYPE, -SAMPLE) %>% 
  group_by(SAMPLE, key, TYPE) %>% 
  summarise(a = mean(value)) %>% 
  spread(TYPE, a) %>% 
  mutate(res = CatA/CatB)

Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: SAMPLE, key [6]
  SAMPLE    key  CatA  CatB       res
   <int>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     52 probeA   1.7  2.20 0.7727273
2     52 probeB   3.7  2.20 1.6818182
3     58 probeA   4.9  4.35 1.1264368
4     58 probeB   6.5  5.25 1.2380952
5     94 probeA   1.5  2.50 0.6000000
6     94 probeB   4.3  5.30 0.8113208
```